# Why can I see invisible mesh faces through transparent faces?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl, voxel

The title might be off, because I'm not 100% sure what is going on. I am working on a voxel engine, and am using LibGDX. I'm constructing each chunk of 16x16 and am only creating faces on my mesh where the sides touch air, or if a non-solid is next to a solid. So as you can see in the attached images; underwater, you don't see any sides of each chunk, but above water you can see it only through the water's transparency. I shouldn't be seeing any of those strange rectangles under water, as it should all be see-through.

I'm not sure what else to share because currently this issue makes no sense to me.

Does anyone have insight into this?

[image: Above water looking into]

[image: Below water]

Comment: Any time you try "transparency" in OpenGL you have to worry about the draw order, since alpha blending isn't commutative. Are you sure you are drawing from back to front (relative to camera) ?
Less likely but still possible is Z fighting, where surfaces have almost the same distance from the camera.
The answer to an awful lot of OpenGL questions is "read the OpenGL SuperBible". It's a great book about 3D and OpenGL

Comment: That was totally the problem. I rendered objects with transparency afterwards, and now it is working properly. I'll checkout the book you mentioned. Thank you!